# is it ok to do Gayatri Japa during a Lunar Eclipse?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, japa, eclipse

For example, there is a Partial Lunar Eclipse taking place  tomorrow ( 7th August 2017 ).
Is performing Gayatri Japa during the Lunar Eclipse (10.52 Pm- 12.48 AM tomorrow)  allowed ?

Regards

Comment: Gyatri japam or sandhyavandanam is not allowed after sunset, and it is forbidden in eclipse time as well.

Comment: any japa is highly recommended during eclipse. you can do the japa. mental chanting is better.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi thanks for the comment. During metal chanting, even the lips shouldn't move right ?

Comment: @Vamsi its not mandatory to do mentally. you can do with lip movement too. For more on eclipse see this thread https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20102/what-is-esoteric-meaning-behind-eclipse-timing-and-spiritual-activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this from [this](http://www.astropeep.com/hindu-practices/lunar-eclipse-chandra-grahan-2017/) website which mentions about Do's and Don'ts during eclipses:

- You should finish your breakfast/lunch/dinner at least 10 hours
  before Eclipse.
- Put minimum 2 blades of darba/kusha (grass) on top of each container
  of food items like, rice, atta, dal, raw vegetables, ghee, milk,
  curd, pickle etc. This darba grass is put to prevent the harmful
  radioactive waves generated during the eclipse from making the food
  harmful to us.
- Any food which is cooked on fire that day and has been consumed
  like,roti, chapatti, rice, sambar/dal,  curry etc should be thrown
  away and not kept in the fridge.
- Uncooked raw items to be used daily/regularly should be protected with
  darba grass blades.
- when the actual Grahan period starts, you should have a head bath
  with clothes on (dhoti and angavastram/uparna) and during the bath
  chant the Grahana protection mantras.
- After bath, change to dry clothes (dhoti and angavastra) and sit on a
  mat and start “Mantra Japa”.

> **Men who have had their upanayan sanskar can do Gayatri Japa. Each
>
>   Gayatri you chant will give you merits or phal of 1 crore Gayatri
>
>   chanting.**

- Those who have not had upanayan sanskar/ladies and children can chant
  any mantra of their Ishta devata. Like “Shivaya Namah”, or “Vishnave
  Namaha” or “Durgayay Namaha” or even slokas or Sahasranamas. This
  mantra Japa should continue till the end of Grahana.
- In case you have some danam (donation) to give then you might have to
  cut short your japa at little before the end of the eclipse and make
  time to give dana.
- Shastras mention you can give gold/silver/rice/clothes/money to a
  needy brahmin.

> So, this website says as per Dharma Sastras it is okay to chant
>   Gayathri Hymn.