# How did ancient Hindus identify the date and time of Eclipses?

Tags: history, eclipse

For example, we have partial lunar eclipse on 7.8.2017. With modern technology, it is possible to discover the date and time of eclipses. But without any modern equipment, how did ancient Hindus identify the time of eclipses to [follow the Do's and Don'ts during Grahana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20078/is-it-ok-to-do-gayatri-japa-during-a-lunar-eclipse/20082#20082)

Comment: Ancient Hindus had their own [Hindu Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar). Using their own created calendar they use to know about time. Rama's and Krishna's birth time is use to celebrate on same day (according to hindu calendar) every year. But our Hindu calendar don't match with today's commonly used calendar. That's why we see different birth date of Lord's every year according to common calendar But according to Hindu Calendar we use to celebrate Birthday of Lord on same day every year.

Comment: Ancient Hindu was even more intelligent that today's scientist. Because they had full knowledge of Space science. They were already aware that Planets are 9 and today's scientist couldn't discover that until they invented telescope. They need machine (telescope) to discover about space's activities but our saints used to do that without help of any machine. Whole working process of solar system and stars is mentioned in books by our saints long long ago. And our Hindu calendar works according to planets activities. That's proofs that saints were aware of all activities of all planets.