# What is esoteric meaning behind eclipse timing?

Tags: rituals, mantras, spirituality, eclipse

It is commonly known idea that merit time is a sacred one and it is suggested that one must do good deeds like sacred bathing, charity, japa, homa, etc. during the eclipse. Activities like eating, sleeping, intercourse, and normal rituals are not recommended during this period.

What is the specialty of this celestial event?

How does it help us to gain better results from spiritual deeds?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is a special celestial event which takes place either on a full moon (lunar) or a new moon day (solar).

As per the traditional belief, good deeds done during this time would give manifold fruits. Hence it is considered as very potent time for the sadhana.

As per astronomy, Sun, Moon, and Earth are in a straight direction during the eclipse. Either Sun's view is blocked by the moon or moon is not seen due to shadow of Earth. In both cases they are in an alignment.

Now how does these planets being in the straight line have any impact on us?

As per the shastrAs,

**Moon signifies the mind,**

> चन्द्रमा मनसो जातश्चक्षोः सूर्यो अजायत । श्रोत्राद्वायुश्च प्राणश्च मुखादग्निरजायत ।। 12 (purusha suktam)

**the Sun signifies Soul/AtmA, (cosmic consciousness)**

> सूर्य आत्मा जगत्स्तथुषश्च - ऋग्वेद

**And the earth signifies physical body.**

Hence during the eclipse tume,  our mind, body, and soul are more in an alignment with each other than the normal time.

The idA  nAdi signifies the moon, the pingalA nAdi signifies the Sun and when both are in alignment, there is high chances of the central nAdi ShushumnA (the passage of kundalini shakti) to get activated.

When sushumna is active, the person has a better ability to dwell within and contemplate or meditate.

> The Varaha Upanishad (13-16 cc. CE) further describes it as follows:
>
> "The **nāḍis** penetrate the body from the soles of the feet to the
>   crown of the head. In them is prāṇa, the breath of life and in that
>   life abides Ātman, which is the abode of **Shakti**, **creatrix** of
>   the animate and inanimate worlds." (VU 54/5)
>
> The medieval **Sat-Cakra-Nirupana** (1520s), one of the later and more
>   fully developed classical texts on nadis and chakras, refers to these
>   three main nadis by the names Sasi, Mihira, and Susumna.
>
> In the space outside the Meru, the right apart from the body placed on
>   the left and the right, are the two Nadis, Sasi (idA) and Mihira (pingala). The Nadi
>   Susumna, whose substance is the threefold Gunas, is in the middle. She
>   is the form of Moon, Sun, and Fire even water also; Her body, a string
>   of blooming Dhatura flowers, extends from the middle of the Kanda to
>   the Head, and the Vajra inside Her extends, shining, from the Medhra
>   to the Head.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadi_(yoga))

Hence this time is a precious time when there are higher chances for shuhumna naadi to be active. One can use this time to advance in spirituality.